# How do I validate the data type of the existing values in selected Cells or Column of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to validate the data value type whether it is integer type or not in the existing cells or column of the DataGridView.

I was able to select the cells in the datagrid and count them then display in a MessageBox how many cells are selected:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 selectedCellCount = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (selectedCellCount > 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.AreAllCellsSelected(true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All cells are selected", "Selected Cells");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb =
                new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0;
                i < selectedCellCount; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("Row: ");
                sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex
                    .ToString());
                sb.Append(", Column: ");
                sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex
                    .ToString());
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            sb.Append("Total: " + selectedCellCount.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Selected Cells");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the existing cell values to be validated if they are of integer type or not and show results in a MessageBox.

Comment: I don't see any validation in your code. Please add a [mcve] of what you're trying to do.

Comment: See the example you can find in the [DataGridView.CellValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating) event. The CellFormatting or CellValidated can also be used. It depends on what action you want to take when a Cell's value does not validate.

Comment: The validation method of choice can change in relation to the DGV's DataSource type, the type of User interaction needed and other factors.